# Inheriting properties from Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Any JavaScript object inherits its properties from Object (unless you do something like `Object.create(null)`). So why is the following not possible?

```
a={x:1,y:2}
    Object {x: 1, y: 2}
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)
    true
a.toString()
   "[object Object]"//YES, BECAUSE a INHERITS OBJECT toString() PROPERTY
a.keys()
   TypeError: undefined is not a function// BUT WHY NOT keys()
Object.keys(a)
   ["x", "y"]// WHILE THE OBJECT HAS keys() METHOD FROM ECMA5 SPECIFICATION
```

Based on my understanding then, the only reason it had not worked should be because `keys()` method is un-inheritable but I have never seen how to make some properties un-inheritable in JavaScript.

Am I missing something about how prototypical chain works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.toString` is inherited from `Object.prototype.toString`, not `Object.toString`. `Object.keys` is not on `Object.prototype`.

You could add it:

```
Object.prototype.keys = function keys() {
    return Object.keys(this);
};
```

(Don’t, of course.)

Comment: Such a nice answer and short! Thanks for clearing the confusion.